# Shiny - Leaflet map is not displaying properly with full screen video

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

I have two tabs in my App and when I go to the video tab and click full screen and then go back to my leaflet page, the map is not displayed properly, please see the code and screenshot below.

- step 1: click video tab
- step 2: click full screen button (of the video)
- step 3: hit ESC key
- step 4: click dashboard tab

ui.R

```
library("shinydashboard")
library("shiny")
library("leaflet")

dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(), 
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = FALSE, 
                             collapsed = FALSE, 
                             sidebarMenu(
                               menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                               menuItem("Video", tabName = "video")
                             )
  ), 
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 9, box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE, leafletOutput("map", height=700)))
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "video",
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 9, tags$video(src = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4", type = "video/mp4", height = "320px", 
                                       weight = "640px", controls = "controls")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library("shinydashboard")
library("shiny")
library("leaflet")

function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -77.0387185, lat = 38.8976763, zoom = 10)
  )
}
```

[image: messed up]

Thanks

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen/issues/53. It seems that you need to force a refresh of the map. For example, I added a fullscreen button to the leaflet map which refreshes it using %>% addFullscreenControl() from the leaflet.extras package.

Comment: I think OP means the video-fullscreen button, as I dont see any other one. And after the video was on fullsize, the leaflet map is not rendered correctly. But yes, it also looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me, but I am not sure on which side, leaflet/shinydashboard or shiny, as this also seems to happen when using `fluidPage` and `tabsetPanel`.

A workaround would be to trigger a fake resize event on the window, as this apparently solves the problem, also when done manually.

The `jscode` waits for a click on the sidebar-menu list and triggers a new resize Event. Make sure to include the Jquery code in the HTML by adding `tags$head(tags$script(jscode))` to the `dashboardBody`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

jscode = HTML("
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
  $('.sidebar-menu li').on('click', function(){
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  });
});
")

ui <- {dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(), 
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = FALSE, 
                             collapsed = FALSE, 
                             sidebarMenu(
                               menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                               menuItem("Video", tabName = "video")
                             )
  ), 
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(jscode)),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 9, box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE, leafletOutput("map", height=700)))
              )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "video",
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 9, tags$video(src = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4", type = "video/mp4", height = "320px", 
                                       weight = "640px", controls = "controls")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -77.0387185, lat = 38.8976763, zoom = 10)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```